# Why is the auto-correlation problem described in terms of correlated error term instead of correlated dependent variable?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, error, assumptions

I know the basic concept of auto-correlation problem, but I cannot understand why it is described in terms of correlated error term, instead of correlated dependent variable.

For example, when it comes to time-series data, $Y_2$ is correlated to $Y_1$ which leads to auto-correlation, but can I say error terms are correlated in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Correlation:

$$Y_t = \alpha +  \beta X + \epsilon$$

Auto-correlation:

$$Y_t = \alpha +  \beta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon$$

Auto-correlation is usually an issue in time series data. While correlation appears in every data set with at least two variables.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Thanks for the comment anyway.